# How can I reset Safari 8 cookies from the command line?

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, safari, private-browsing

### How can I reset Safari 8 cookies from the command line?

I've read the question [Reset Safari from command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144311/reset-safari-from-command-line) which seems to work fine for Safari 7, but this method no longer seems to work with Safari 8 (on Mac OS X Yosemite).

It appears that the `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/` is the location where Safari stores the files, but if I quit safari, delete that directory, and then restart Safari, the files that were there just come back. Safari must be storing the data elsewhere, too - but I can not find this location.

I have tried also doing `killall cookied` and `killall -9 cookied` and also killing `SafariNotificationAgent` but this seems to have no effect.

I have attempted to watch what files are being accessed by Safari using `sudo fs_usage Safari` but this does not give me much help, either.

I have also researched "alternatives" that would yield the same result without luck:

- A way to start Safari in Private Browsing mode ( only found a hacky applescript way to do it )
- A way to clear all cookies on exit - maybe an extension? ( no luck with this, either )

**The method from the link above to work fine on Safari 7.**

How can the same thing be done with Safari 8?

Answer (score 0):

The article [Deleting Safari cookies via AppleScript](http://leancrew.com/all-this/2013/03/deleting-safari-cookies-via-applescript/) suggests this script
for deleting the cookies of three specific websites :

```
set deCookie to {"nytimes.com", "go.com", "cnn.com"}
tell application "System Events"
  tell process "Safari"
    keystroke "," using command down
    delay 1
    tell window 1
      click button "Privacy" of tool bar 1
      delay 3
      repeat with d in deCookie
        click button "Details…" of group 1 of group 1
        try
          keystroke d
          delay 1
          select row 1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of sheet 1
          click button "Remove" of sheet 1
        end try
        click button "Done" of sheet 1
      end repeat
    end tell
    keystroke "w" using command down
  end tell
end tell
```

Written in 2013, this script might need to be adapted to Safari 8.

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I've used OS X but in the past you could get at the cookies via deleting the files within the app itself. Have you poked around in `Safari.app` directory? Find the local storage in there and delete the directory you were removing before, and start Safari.